# help optimize sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, optimization

I have tracking table tbl_track with id, session_id, created_date fields

I need count unique session_id for one day

here what i got:

```
select count(0) 
from (
       select distinct session_id
       from tbl_track 
       where created_date between getdate()-1 and getdate()
       group by session_id
)tbl
```

im feeling that it could be better solution for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select count(distinct session_id)
from tbl_track
where created_date between getdate()-1 and getdate()
```

Comment: but here i will get many rows (count for each session_id), but what i need is one row with count of all unique session_id

Answer (score 5):

Why not just do exactly what you ask for?

```
   select count(distinct session_id)
   from tbl_track  
   where created_date between getdate()-1 and getdate()
```